# julia double for loops, looping over dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, julia

I have just started using Julia. To my understanding Julia allows you to declare multiple for loops on a single line.

For example, this:

```
for i = 1:2, j = [-1,-2]
    println((i, j))
end
```

Will result in this:

```
(1,-1)
(1,-2)
(2,-1)
(2,-2)
```

I am now doing something similar but while looping over dictionaries. I declare the following:

```
rename = function(x)
    x["num"] = -x["num"]
    x
end

players1 = [["num" => 1],["num" => 2]]
players2 = map(rename, copy(players1)) # = [["num" => -1],["num" => -2]]
```

Oddly, to me, when I do this:

```
for i=players1, j=players2
    println(i, j)
end
```

Why don't I get this output?

```
["num"=>1]["num"=>-1]
["num"=>1]["num"=>-2]
["num"=>2]["num"=>-1]
["num"=>2]["num"=>-2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. The `map` functions still needs a `deepcopy` in this case.

This snippet of code does seem to work.

```
rename = function(x)
    x["num"] = -x["num"]
    x
end

players1 = [["num" => 1],["num" => 2]]
players2 = map(rename, deepcopy(players1))

for i=players1, j=players2
    println(i, j)
end
```